# Can os.system command in python behave differently on Windows 7 and windows 10?

Tags: python, bash, windows-7, windows-10, wait

I have the following python script which tries to launch two bash scripts using os.system call
the content of the bash scripts are provided here;

observation: on windows10; i see the following sequence

1. execute the concurrenttest.sh (waits for 10 seconds, prints and returns)
2. Prints ok
3. execute the concurrenttest1.sh (waits for 5 seconds, prints and returns)
4. Prints done

On windows7 running on VM; I notice "ok" and "done" are getting printed while the scripts are still being executed in the background;

1. execute the concurrenttest.sh (doesn't wait)
2. Prints ok
3. execute the concurrenttest1.sh (doesn't wait)
4. Prints done

python script >>>>>

```
import os
os.system("C:/Users/concurrenttest.sh")
print("ok")
os.system("C:/Users/concurrenttest1.sh")
print("done")
```

concurrenttest.sh >>>>>

```
sleep 10
echo "This is from first script"
```

concurrenttest1.sh >>>>>

```
sleep 5
echo "This is from second script"
```

Comment: try this, os.system("sh C:/Users/concurrenttest.sh")

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please write me what "sh", that you've added, is for?

Comment: There's no difference in Python and no relevant difference in CMD. The only significant variable here is how .sh scripts are configured to execute on the two systems. It appears that bash.exe in Windows 7 is spawning another instance of itself to execute the script and then not waiting for that bash process to exit. If the first bash process exits immediately, then so will CMD and `system` will return with the exit code from the first process.